# ASP.NET button on page stops playing video

Tags: asp.net, forms, video-streaming

I have a ASP.NET page with a video (mp4 in  tags) and a ASP:Button.  The button is initially disabled; after 20 seconds a  goes off and enables the button.  However, if the video is playing while this happens, the video stops and goes back to the beginning.

I put them in an UpdatePanel, but that didn't help.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What event triggers post back that enables button? Is it Ajax Timer?

Comment: I'm sorry i left that out.  I have an ASP:Timer that goes off after 20 seconds.  The Tick event is where the button is being enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must place button and timer within same update panel and make it's UpdateMode to be 'Conditional' but I think that you can achieve it using javascript much simpler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(
        function () { document.getElementById('buttonClientID').removeAttribute("disabled"); }, 20000);
    });
</script>
```

Above scripts uses jquery for '$(document).ready' part but 'setTimeout' could be place at the end of the page for the same effect.

Comment: Thank you very much, the javascript worked perfectly, did exactly what i needed it to do.  I appreciate your help.